# What is definiteness of matrix $A+A^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

a)What is definiteness of matrix $A+A^{*}$ if matrix $A$ is defined
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 3 \\
    1 & -3 & -2 \\
    -1 & 0 & -3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \\ $$ b)Using conclusion from a), prove that real part of all matrix $A$ eigenvalues is negative. $$--------------------------------------$$ Is $A^{*}$ *conjugate-transpose matrix*? If it is, it should look like matrix A in a  *conjugate-transpose* . Because matrix $A$ doesn't have complex elements, is then matrix $A+A^{*}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 3 \\
    1 & -3 & -2 \\
    -1 & 0 & -3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & -1 \\
    1 & -3 & 0 \\
    3 & -2 & -3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \\[1ex] ?$

Comment: "Is $A^*$ conjugate-transpose matrix (of $A$)?" Usually, yes. What is the **definition** in *your* book/notes?

Comment: Yes, it says exactly that. So, here I get $\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 2 & 2 \\
    2 & -6 & -2 \\
    2 & -2 & -6 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ So I have a new matrix that is symmetric..with all diagonal elements lower than 0. I can use one more method, Sylvester's criterion to see if it is negative definite. But how can I prove b) ?

Comment: Do you have difficulties finding all the eigenvalues?

Comment: No, I can find them  $4,\sqrt{17} - 5, - 5 - \sqrt{17}$. I wrote wrong, i have to use conclusion from a) and than to prove b), without accually calculationg eigenvalues..

Answer (score 1):

a) We can calculate the eigenvalues of $A+A^*$ or check the principle minors to find it is negative definite.

That means that for any $x\ne 0$ we have $x^* (A+A^*)x <0$.

b) Since $(A+A^*)$ is negative definite, we have for every eigenvector $v$ of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$:
$$v^*(A+A^*)v = v^*Av +(Av)^*v = v^*\lambda v + (\lambda v)^*v = \lambda v^2 + \lambda^* v^2 = 2\Re(\lambda) v^2 < 0$$
Therefore $\Re(\lambda)<0$.